# Stopping mediaplayer using mediaplayer.stop is not working

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-mediaplayer

I am new in android programming. I have a problem in stopping mediaplayer when I click the button for stop. I think I have some problem with my code because my sounds are looping that's is why mp.stop(); is not working or probably because of the sleep? I am not sure. Is there anyone who can help me with these? Thanks in advance.

Here is my code for stop:

```
bb5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0){

        if (mp.isPlaying()){
            mp.stop();
        }

    } // END onClick()
});
```

Here is my code for playing the sound:

```
protected void managerOfSound() {
    int size = tempq.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < tempq.size(); i++) {
        String u =tempq.get(i);

        //WHOLE
        if (u.equals("a4")){
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a4);
            mp.start();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            }

        }else if (u.equals("b4")){
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.b4);
            mp.start();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            }

        }else if (u.equals("c4")){
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.c4);
            mp.start();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            }
```

Comment: Are you calling managerOfSound() on main (UI) thread? If yes then your click on button bb5 won't be performed because UI thread is locked by Thread.sleep(...).

Comment: Why are you using `Thread.sleep()`?

Comment: bb1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0){

   managerOfSound();
  
  } // END onClick()
    });

Comment: bb1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0){

   managerOfSound();
  
  } // END onClick()
    });

Comment: managerOfSound is called when bb1 button is clicked.

Comment: i am using thread.sleep so that the sounds won't overlap.

Comment: i tried deleting the thread.sleep then the button for stop works. so the main problem is the thread.sleep. i already tried interrupting or stopping the thread but it's not working too. is there anyone who can suggest to me how to stop the thread when button click? is there any possible way to stop it?